# Check the user input if it is between certain numbers and not zero

Tags: c#, list, struct, enums

This is the code I came up with in my C# assignment as a part of the game `connect four`, but it still allows the user to enter zero. I tried different ways I thought of, but did not solve my problem. I would like to share some suggestions. I am new in coding and am still struggling to understand some terms that are used.

```
public void PromptUser()
{
    Console.Write("Column Number (1 -7): ");
    int userInput = 0;
    while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out userInput))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid input. Please enter a number (1 - 7)");
    }
    int[,] tempKup = new int[kupsekerler.GetLength(0),  kupsekerler.GetLength(1)];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

YOu can use

readKey

see   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readkey(v=vs.110).aspx

and get only one key.

You can then check if it is smaller than "1" or bigger than "7"

An example of using readKey in

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: ConsoleModifiers.Control != 0 <=== this helped. Thanks so much. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public void PromptUser()  
{
  Console.Write("Column Number (1 -7): ");
  int userInput = 0;
  while (userInput < 1 || userInput > 7)
  {
    String sInput = Console.ReadLine();
    bool bValid = int.TryParse(sInput, out userInput);
    If (!bValid || userInput < 1 || userInput > 7)
      Console.WriteLine("Invalid input. Please enter a number (1 - 7)");
  }
...
}
```

Close to your post with little modification.

Comment: @Alex, When you learn coding, you should keep the commands separated (makes it easier to understand and debug), not concatenated and cobined like in your post.